# Converting gl.blendFunc/gl.blendEquation arguments into gl.blendFuncSeparate/gl.blendEquationSeparate

Tags: webgl, opengl-es-2.0

Is the `gl.blendFunc(A,B)` same as `gl.blendFuncSeparate(A,B,A,B)` or `gl.blendFuncSeparate(A,B,ONE,ZERO)`?

And is `gl.blendEquation(A)` same as `gl.blendEquation(A,A)` or `gl.blendEquation(A,FUNC_ADD)`?

Is there any documentation written about this parameter conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gl.blendFunc(A,B)
```

is exactly equal to

```
gl.blendFunc(A,B,A,B)
```

From the function's page on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/blendFuncSeparate

we can see the function's syntax

```
void gl.blendFuncSeparate(srcRGB, dstRGB, srcAlpha, dstAlpha);
```

It helps if you think at those parameters as constants to be multiplied with the corresponding parameters name e.g.

```
gl.blendFuncSeparate(SRC_ALPHA,  //sourcRGB will be multiplied by SRC_ALPHA
ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,             //destinationRGB will be multiplied by ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA 
SRC_ALPHA,                       //sourceALPHA will be multiplied by SRC_ALPHA
ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);            //destinationALPHA will be multiplied by ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA
```

The same apply for gl.blendEquation() and blendEquationSeparate() where you can specify different equations for the RGB colors and the alpha value, by default in gl.blendEquation the same equation is applied to both rgb and alpha values.

To understand better how the whole opengl blending system work check this great webpage from andersriggelsen.dk
http://andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php

Answer (score 0):

From [man](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendEquation.xml) [pages](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml):

> This function sets both the RGB blend equation and the alpha blend equation to a single equation.
>
> Each method defines four scale factors, one each for red, green, blue, and alpha.

So, the first option: `gl.blendFunc(A, B)` is the same as `gl.blendFuncSeparate(A, B, A, B)`.